# String to Int to Byte

Tags: c#

Hi I need to read an int from excel cell and send it in one byte but when I do it with this code:

```
cert1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(
    "write" + flg + 
    dataRow[3].ToString() + 
    dataRow[4].ToString() + 
    dataRow[5].ToString().Substring(0,4) + 
    dataRow[5].ToString().Substring(5,2) + 
    dataRow[5].ToString().Substring(8,2) + 
    dataRow[6].ToString() + 
    dataRow[7].ToString() + 
    dataRow[8].ToString() + 
    dataRow[10].ToString().Substring(0, 4) + 
    dataRow[10].ToString().Substring(5, 2) + 
    dataRow[10].ToString().Substring(8, 2) + 
    dataRow[11].ToString());
comport.Write(cert1, 0, cert1.Length);
```

and debug it, I get two byte for number 12 which in excel cell. It means it thinks 12 as string and returns 1 as one byte and 2 as another. I assume I need to use this `Int.Parse()` to look at 12 as one int and convert it to binary and after that to byte.

Am I right? If yes how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and your code is likely to be wrong.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you only have one byte to work with, then the largest possible number you will be able to represent is 255 (assuming an unsigned integer).

Comment: I have an excel file which contains some cells with integer values. I want to read excel and send to serial port so I need to convert them to byte. I read from excel without any problem and send to serial port without problem as well. I use `GetBytes()` and it gives me two bytes for integer 12 But I want to send one byte . How to do it?

Comment: @Douglas Barbin most of my integers are less than 255 and for larger values I consider two bytes

Comment: Parse your string into an integer with `int.Parse()` and if your sure its < 256 cast the int to a byte: `(byte)int.Parse(inputString)`

Comment: no it still returns two bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting the bytes from the characters not the ints
for example if you have `dataRow[3] = 12`
then in your case you will get the bytes for 1 and 2 as you saw.

you need to use
`BitConverter.GetBytes(Int.Parse(dataRow[3].ToString()));`
for the field

so you have to do this for all the fields and then combine the arrays.
you can use `System.Buffer.BlockCopy` for that.
in [this article](http://blog.djodjo.org/?p=236) there are some examples how to do that

Answer (score 1):

I think that the conversion `Byte.Parse()` is probably what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4eszwye3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you call `GetBytes` for string `12` you're going to get two bytes: `'1'` and  and `'2'`. If you want to get a byte with value 12, the you have to convert the string to integer first and then get the bytes of it. There are different ways to parse an integer from a string (`int.Parse()` or `int.TryParse()` are two of them).